# Customize each single Navigation Tabs separately using Actionbar java

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs, android-actionbar, customization

i am using ActionBar to create an android app in eclipse with Tab Navigations and i would like to customize each of my tabs separately to add custom background color and icon to them. How can i set background, and icon to a tab on the ActionBar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a workaround for this problem. I'm still unable to customize each tab separately, but i can load a drawable background to the Navigation Tab Bar in the XML;

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/tab_bg</item>
    <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
</style>
```

The result is the following, which is exactly what i wanted;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKnDr.png

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Android project/Android Activity, there are some templates you can choose from. Once of those should be for a tabbed navigation activity using ActionBar tabs. Somewhere in the generated code you'll see it's creating instances of `ActionBar.Tab` and adding them to the `ActionBar`. You can call [setIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setIcon%28int%29) on the `ActionBar.Tab`s.

For theme customization, I recommend you use this website, it will generate all the necessary drawables and xml resources, and you can just drop those all into your project. [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=33B5E5,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100)

Comment: Alright, but the tricky part is, i would like to customize the tabs differently. But now i can change the theme for all of them. Let me show you an example; http://i.imgur.com/Zzgp5A4.jpg

How can i do that?

Comment: Well, your image resources for the tab icons could just be different.